# Is planned an upgrade for the"Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio" extension which use the latest version of cordova

Tags: android, security, cordova, version, visual-studio-cordova

Yesterday, Google Play Developer Support sent us a email saying that we need to upgrade our apps targeting a cordova versión upper than 3.5.0 due a security vulnerability.

I need to know if I can wait or come back to the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for higher versions of Cordova is planned for the next version of MDHA tools. It seems like the Android issue was [fixed](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/08/13/tools-update.html) with Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7.

To manually update your cordova version, please follow the steps below

1. Open the command prompt
2. Type `cd %appdata%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\`
3. Type `npm install cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7`. **Make sure you do not use -g**
4. Run a "clean" on any project you want to upgrade

This will update your Cordova Android to 3.5.1. If you are building for iOS, you would need to do the same thing to patch `vs-mda-remote`

1. Shut down vs-mda-remote if it is running
2. Open Terminal
3. Go to the location you installed vs-mda-remote. Typically `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote`
4. Type `sudo npm install cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7` **Important: Be sure to omit -g**

Comment: After I did the clean step, and rebuild my project, it shows error:
... 1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda (TaskId:9)
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.19 (TaskId:9)
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.2 (TaskId:9)
1>  ------ Current globally installed version different from package version. Will install from source package. (TaskId:9)
...
It appears that C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\bg0i5k0d.22q\packages\vs-mda\package.json still has the old version with old cordova dependency.  Should I manualy edit it?

Comment: After manually edit the package.json file to match the versions of cordova and node.js, i.e. version from 0.1.19 to 0.1.2 , and cordova dependency from 3.5.0-0.2.4 to 3.5.0-0.2.7, it works fine